# How to start application Maximized on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, application-launch

I would like to know - how to start an application Maximized using a .bat file. On Windows 10 operating system. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this with standard Windows commands, whether with CMD, VBS or PS scripts. What does work is the (freeware) extended CMD replacement [TCC-LE](https://jpsoft.com/all-downloads/downloads.html), which has many enhancements, including the `/fs` option to the `start` command. Note that if an application needs quoting then it must be preceded by a quoted window title (which can be an empty string), eg `start "" "Application Name.exe"` - this applies to both CMD and TCC-LE.

Comment: In general you can't, as not all applications actually have (support) a full screen mode, and those that do have different command line switches to do so.

Comment: If there is really no way to implement the full screen of application through these files, you can try to change the registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afternoon,

You can use the following to start an application in full screen:

Inside a batch-file put the following, replace notepad.exe with the application.

```
start /max notepad.exe
```

I am unsure if this will be applicable to all applications but I have tested with notepad and MS Word.

Comment: This starts an application maximised, not full-screen, as the questioner wants.